# Regex in C, check if string contains specific characters

Tags: c, regex

I want to have a regex that contains one and only one "-", followed by "s" or "h".
So, "-shshshshs" would match, "-ssssss" would too, but "-so" would not match, neither would "sh".

So far, I only succeeded to match "if strings contains "-" and "s" or "h", but typing "-sho" is accepted.

```
/* Compile regular expression */
reti = regcomp(&regex, "-[sh]", 0);
if (reti) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* Execute regular expression */
reti = regexec(&regex, "--sh", 0, NULL, 0);
if (!reti) {
    puts("Match");
} else {
    puts("No match");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your regex engine supports it:

```
"-[sh]+$"
```

Otherwise:

```
"-[sh][sh]*$"
```

Comment: @Synor: You might need to add `^` at the start (before the dash) if the `-sh` is meant to be at the start of the line or string you're scanning.